# Flutter: Laggy performance with PageView when updating the currentIndex in a BottomNavigationBar (but no lag if I don't update the currentIndex)

Tags: flutter, dart, lag

I'm creating an app with a Scaffold that contains:

- A `FutureBuilder` in the body that creates a `PageView` as its child when data is loaded.
- A `BottomNavigationBar` that syncs with the `PageView` for a more intuitive navigation.

Functionality-wise, everything works fine. I can swipe left and right between pages and the `currentIndex` gets updated correctly in the `BottomNavigationBar`, and if I tap on the `BottomNavigationBar` elements the `PageView` will animate to the correct page as expected.

However... performance is **really** bad when switching between pages, even in Profile mode.

After a lot of investigation, I've confirmed that lag is only present **if I update the `currentIndex` of the `BottomNavigationBar`.**

If I don't update the `BottomNavigationBar`, animations remain very smooth when switching between pages, both when swiping on the `PageView` and when tapping on the `BottomNavigationBar` elements themselves.

I can also confirm that this happens exactly the same when using `setState` and when using `Provider`. I was really hoping that it was just the `setState` method being inefficient... but no luck :(

For the `setState` impementation, this is what I'm doing:

On the `PageView`:

```
onPageChanged: (page) {
  setState(() {
    _selectedIndex = page;
  });
}
```

On the BottomBarNavigation:

```
onTap: _onTappedBar,
currentIndex: _selectedIndex
```

and below:

```
void _onTappedBar(int value) {
  _pageController.animateToPage(value, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
  setState(() {
    _selectedIndex = value;
  });
}
```

If I comment out both `setState` methods, the app becomes buttery smooth again and I can use the `BottomNavigationBar` correctly as well - it just doesn't update the selected item.

Interestingly enough, if I ONLY comment out the line inside both `setState` methods (`_selectedIndex = page;` and `_selectedIndex = value;`) but leave the methods there, **the app still lags all the same** even though the `setState` methods are completely empty and aren't updating anything...??

And this is the `Provider` version:

On the `PageView`:

```
onPageChanged: (page) {
  Provider.of<BottomNavigationBarProvider>(context, listen: false).currentIndex = page;
}
```

On the `BottomBarNavigation`:

```
onTap: _onTappedBar,
currentIndex: Provider.of<BottomNavigationBarProvider>(context).currentIndex,
```

and below:

```
void _onTappedBar(int value) {
  Provider.of<BottomNavigationBarProvider>(context, listen: false).currentIndex = value;
  pageController.animateToPage(value, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
}
```

As said, just as laggy as the `setState` version :(

Any idea of what's causing this lag and how to fix this? I really don't know what else to try.

Comment: Seems that there is a widget cause the laggy problem when rebuild. A stupid method: Remove one by one of the widget to see which one cause this problem, or build profile version and use dev tool to look at the timeline. Did you used MediaQuery.of(context) ? I met the laggy problem last time is due to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so I think I managed to solve it while also learning a valuable lesson about Flutter!

I was on the right track with the `setState` / `Provider` dilemma - you *do* need to use `Provider` (or another state management solution) if you want to avoid rebuilding the whole page.

However, that's not enough.

In order to leverage the modularity of that implementation, you ALSO need to extract the relevant widget (in this case, the whole `BottomNavigationBar`) outside the main widget. If you don't, it seems everything on the main page will still get rebuilt, even if only a small widget is listening for `Provider` notifications.

So this is the structure of my `root_screen`'s `build` method now (simplified body contents for readaibility):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: PageView(
      controller: _pageController,
        children: <Widget>[
          HomeScreen(),
          PerformanceScreen(),
          SettingsScreen(),
        ],
      onPageChanged: (page) {
        Provider.of<BottomNavigationBarProvider>(context, listen: false).currentIndex = page;
      },
    );
    bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomNavigationBar(onTapped: _onTappedBar),
  );
}
```

Notice how the `bottomNavigationBar:` parameter is no longer defined in this `root_screen`. Instead, I've created a new class (a `StatelessWidget`) in a separate Dart file that takes in an `onTapped` function as a parameter, and I'm instantiating it from here.

Said `_onTappedBar` function is defined right here on the `root_screen`, just below the `build` method:

```
void _onTappedBar(int value) {
  Provider.of<BottomNavigationBarProvider>(context, listen: false).currentIndex = value;
  _pageController.animateToPage(value, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
}
```

And this is the separate Dart file containing the new `MyBottomNavigationBar` class:

```
class MyBottomNavigationBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  const MyBottomNavigationBar({
    Key key,
    @required this.onTapped,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final Function onTapped;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.trending_up), title: Text('Performance')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings), title: Text('Settings')),
      ],
      onTap: onTapped,
      currentIndex:
          Provider.of<BottomNavigationBarProvider>(context).currentIndex,
    );
  }
}
```

Also for completeness (and because I absolutely needed to know), I tried using the `setState` approach again while keeping the `BottomNavigationBar` in its new separate file. I wanted to understand if simply extracting the widgets was enough to do the trick, or if you still need to use a state management solution no matter what.

It turns out... it wasn't enough! Performance using setState was horrible again, even though the BottomNavigationBar widget was extracted in its own class file.

So bottom line, in order to keep your app efficient and animations smooth, remember to **extract widgets and modularise your Flutter code as much as possible**, as well as using a state management solution instead of `setState`. That seems to be the only way to avoid unnecessary redraws (and your code will obviously be much cleaner and easier to debug).